# Set a retention policy for ActiveMQ Artemis dead-letter queues?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there a best practice on setting a retention policy on ActiveMQ Artemis dead-letter queues?

I was looking through the documentation, but I cannot find anything related. My best approach would be calling `removeMessages(string)` with a filter `AMQTimestamp > TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real best practice here as it's really dependent on use-case and use-cases vary widely in their needs this regard.

Using `removeMessages(string)` with a filter `AMQTimestamp > TIMESTAMP` is certainly fine when you want to remove messages administratively (or even potentially with a script). However, if you want to set up something more automated you can just use the [`expiry-delay`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html) address setting, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting match="myAddress">
   <expiry-delay>300000</expiry-delay> <!-- 300 seconds (5 minutes) -->
</address-setting>
```

If there's no expiry address defined then the messages will simply be removed after the `expiry-delay` elapses. If there *is* an expiry address defined (e.g. in a parent's `address-setting`) then those messages will be routed to any queues bound to that address according to the configured routing type(s). However, if you want to remove the expiry address so that the messages are just dropped then you can, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting match="myAddress">
   <expiry-address/>
   <expiry-delay>300000</expiry-delay> <!-- 300 seconds (5 minutes) -->
</address-setting>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Short follow-up: Do you know whether the expiry of a message is kept when it is moved to the DLQ? Asking because the documentation says that expiry will NOT be overwritten if explicitly set. Only when the default expiry is used.

Comment: It is not kept.

Comment: Works nice to drop expired messages, but there's a WARNING in the log, on startup: "AMQ222147: Messages are being expired on queue xxx, but there is no Expiry Address configured so messages will be dropped.".

Would be nice if the use of <expiry-address/>  wouldn't produce a warning (or if there was a default value, like DROP, which wouldn't produce a warning)

Comment: Currently there is no facility for configuring a policy like `DROP` with regards to message expiration, and adding such a facility seems like a nonstarter to me. The use of `<expiry-address/>` (i.e. explicitly defining no expiry address) may be viable. You could also modify the logging configuration to omit any log with `AMQ222147` in it.